# PC resets triggered by vibration

Tags: troubleshooting, hardware-failure

Having trouble with a PC that resets frequently (monitors turn black, then BIOS boot up screen appears a few seconds later).  The cause appears to be vibration; in fact I can tap the case in a particular way that makes it reset more often than not.  Troubleshooting steps I have taken so far:

- Replace power cord (twice)
- Visual inspection of motherboard for loose connections
- Remove reset switch connection to motherboard
- Replace power supply (upgrading from 500W to 650W, just in case).

None of these has made the slightest difference.  Does anyone have suggestions for next steps?

Comment: perhaps the mb is shorting against the case?

Comment: Something that cause the reset like that its the heat, the computer its running cold?

Comment: Temperature is looking normal (MB temp ~45C, processor ~55C).  Also, I can make it happen within about 5 seconds of turning the machine on, so pretty sure it's not a cooling issue.

Comment: Will try taking the mb out and seeing if there's anything loose behind it, thanks.  Doesn't appear to be anything on the component side that could be causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the power supply.  Put a third PSU in, and it's now running stably.  I guess the moral is, don't *entirely* rule out the possibility that the bizarre symptoms you see are down to the very unlikely coincidence of two new or nearly-new pieces of equipment from different manufacturers failing in exactly the same way at almost the same time.